# Using the find method to find next available blank row

Tags: vba, excel

Column A has tag numbers that vary based on the prefix to that tag number. for example:

- 35C-1234
- blank row here
- 35C-1236
- 35C-1237
- 35TC-1234
- 35TC-1235
- Blank row here
- 35TC-1237

what I am looking to have the macro do is find the first occurrence of a blank row after the user inputs the tag number prefix. In this case, if the user were wanting to find a blank row for the tag number prefix of "35TC" then the blank row  after tag number "35TC-1235" would be selected and not the blank row after tag number "35C-1234". I got the code to find a blank row however, I am having trouble implementing the .Find() function into this code and would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Code being used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()    
    Dim msg As String
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim x As String
    msg = "Would you like to find the next available tag number?"
    result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)

    If result = vbYes Then
        x = Application.InputBox("Enter the part reference ")
'need to work on the find function here
        Cells.Find(What:=c, Lookin:=range("A"))

        NextFree = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
        Range("A" & NextFree).Select
    Else
        Cancel = True       
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit to question:

Through the help of the two answers below, I have been able to get the space after the prefix has been declared by the user. I now am running into two problems, where 1) If the declared prefix does not have a blank row, the code will jump to the next available blank row even if it has a different prefix. Instead of that happening i would like for it to maybe go to the very last tag containing the prefix and output a message declaring that the prefix does not have any blank rows. 2)  I also just added a new prefix "35CA". Now when I go to search "35C" the prefix of "35CA" is included in that. How do I keep it to just give me results pertaining to exactly what I searched for?

[image]

In this case, if i searched for "35C" the code will then jump down to the blank after "35CA-1600-K02". This is an example where both problems explained above occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way it this...

```
Sub FindBlankRow()
Dim Rng As Range, eRng As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim str As String
str = InputBox("Enter the part reference ")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each eRng In Rng.Areas
        If InStr(LCase(eRng.Cells(1).Offset(-1, 0)), LCase(str)) > 0 Then
            eRng.Cells(1).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next eRng
End If
End Sub
```

**Edited Answer:**

```
Sub FindBlankRow()
Dim Cell As Range
Dim str As String, firstcell As String
str = InputBox("Enter the part reference ")
If str = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(str, 1) <> "-" Then str = str & "-"    
With Range("A:A")
    Set Cell = .Find(str, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
        firstcell = Cell.Address
        Do
            If Cell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
                Cell.Select
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(Cell.Offset(1, 0)), LCase(str)) = 0 Then
                Cell.Select
                MsgBox "No blank cell was found below a code with prefix " & str & ".", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
        Loop While Not Cell Is Nothing And firstcell <> Cell.Address
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I run the code it also does what @BruceWayne's code did and gives me results for prefixes that I did not search for.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the screenshot of the data you are running the code on and mention the search string and the expected output in that case?

Comment: I have updated the question and included a screenshot

Comment: You said "if i searched for "35C" the code will then jump down to the blank after "35CA-1600-K02". This is an example where both problems explained above occur." Then what do you expect in that case? Which cell needs to be selected based on that search string?

Comment: Got it. That means you are not including the hyphen "-" in the search string and if you search for 35C only you don't want the code to select any cell as there is not blank row below the codes prefixes with "35C-". Right?

Comment: Yes you are correct in that. What I am wanting it to do in the case where there is no blank space is for it to jump to the last cell containing "35C" which would be "35C-1623-K01" and output a message stating that there are no blank cells.

Comment: Okay I have added an edited answer. Let me know if that works fine for you.

Comment: Seems to be working great! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: (@Pvelez_3 - if it's working for you (yay!), you can mark it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows).

Comment: @sknteer I seem to have run across a problem. I have a prefix of just "V-" (starting at cell A1293) and when I try and run the code on this prefix the code tells me that I do not have a blank with this prefix and I am taken to an earlier cell containing "A101-VAV-01" (found on cell A13). Now I know this has to do with the Matchcase:=False so I changed that to true and I still get the same output. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pvelez_3 Please open a new question and share the screenshot of the data you are talking about and the code you are using so that other members can also look at it.

Comment: Ok and i'll tag you in that post

Answer (score 1):

First, you're looking for `c`, which you never define/declare.  Also, you probably want to use a `Range` variable to store the next non-empty cell.

Try this:

```
Sub find_value()
Dim msg As String, lookForValue As String
Dim result As Integer
Dim foundCell As Range, emptyCell As Range

msg = "Would you like to find the next available tag number?"
result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)

If result = vbYes Then
    lookForValue = Application.InputBox("Enter the part reference ")
    'need to work on the find function here
    Set foundCell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=lookForValue & "*")
    Debug.Print foundCell.Address
    Set emptyCell = foundCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    ' Now you have your cell. Do whatever with it...
    MsgBox ("The next empty cell is " & emptyCell.Address)
Else
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Note: For some reason, it's not using `$A$2` for the first blank cell if you search for `35C`, but let me work on that.  It may help if you could post a little more data and examples, to add some "error" handling.

Comment: I ran your code and it seemed to work (so thank you for that) however I just want it to activate the blank cell, print out the location of it. Also can you explain your line of code "Set foundCell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=lookForValue & "*")  ". what is the purpose of the & "*" part of it?

Comment: @Pvelez_3 - Look carefully I did `...What:=lookForValue & "*"`. Note the `*`. That acts as a wildcard, so it'll look for that value and anything after it. (On second thought, that may not actually be necessary).  If you want to activate that cell, just change the messagebox line to `emptyCell.Select`.  Edit: Just tested, yeah the wildcard part isn't required, but doesn't hurt AFAIK.

Comment: ok thank you for clearing that up. I just ran the code and decided to do as test run in which I removed and blank cells that were in the "35C" range of tag numbers. In doing so the code then gave me the next blank pertaining to a different prefixed tag number. how do I keep it from doing that and maybe selecting the last cell in which still has the prefix that the user inputs and then outputting a message stating that there are no spaces within that prefix?

Comment: @Pvelez_3 - Yeah there's a way to do that. But to clarify, when you removed `35C...` what did you search for, that it found hits?

Comment: I did not remove the tags containing the "35C" prefix, I just removed the spaces that were in the "35C" range. So when I searched for "35C" as the prefix, there was no blank row in that range so it gave me the next blank row available which was in a different range with the prefix being "35E". I also just added a new prefix "35CA". Now when I go to search "35C" the prefix of "35CA" is included in that. How do I keep it to just give me results pertaining to exactly what I searched for?